# Написание слова: необязательно или не обязательно?

Tags: частица-не

Кое-что притормаживает, это из-за того-то? Ответ: -Необязательно

Answer (score 2):

В данном конкретном случае писать надо раздельно. В Большом толковом словаре русского языка написано: Необязательно - нареч. Не обязательно - в знач.сказ. (читать эту книгу не обязательно). [Грамота.ру](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%ED%E5%EE%E1%FF%E7%E0%F2%E5%EB%FC%ED%EE&all=x)